# How to document a string type in jsdoc with limited possible values

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure, jsdoc, code-documentation

I am having a function that accepts one string parameter. This parameter can have only one of a few defined possible values. What is the best way to document the same? Should shapeType be defined as enum or TypeDef or something else?

```
Shape.prototype.create = function (shapeType) {
    // shapeType can be "rect", "circle" or "ellipse"...
    this.type = shapeType;
};

Shape.prototype.getType = function (shapeType) {
    // shapeType can be "rect", "circle" or "ellipse"...
    return this.type;
};
```

The second part of the problem is that the possible values of `shapeType` is not known in the file that defines `shapeType` as whatever you suggest. There are multiple files contributed by several developers who might add to the possible values of `shapeType`.

PS: Am using `jsdoc3`

Comment: The multiple files problem makes this difficult. I usually see an `enum` for the definition and a union for the function parameter: `ShapeType|string`. However enums don't support adding subtypes after declaration in Closure-compiler.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth I see what you mean. I am stuck at a point where I want to define a set of properties (lets say an object that goes as construction parameter of a class). It is well and good had all properties of the construction was defined at one location. Unfortunately, my code has a number of modules contributing to that construction properties. Doing something like a mixin or subclassing the propertied would be going overboard! As such, if I can simply inject to a property list definition it would be great.

Comment: Another similar issue that I am facing, but with distributed property listing is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113571/adding-sub-properties-to-an-existing-property-list-in-jsdoc

Comment: All solutions below force us to create an Enum. There is an active feature request at GitHub to make this process much easier: https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/629. So anybody who likes it should probably bump it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

How about declaring a dummy enum:

```
/**
 * Enum string values.
 * @enum {string}
 */
Enumeration = {
    ONE: "The number one",
    TWO: "A second number"
};

/**
 * Sample.
 * @param {Enumeration} a one of the enumeration values.
 */
Bar.prototype.sample = function(a) {};


b = new Bar();

bar.sample(Enumeration.ONE)
```

You need to at least declare the enum to JSDOC, for this, though. But the code is clean and you get auto-completion in WebStorm.

The multiple files problem though cannot be solved this way.

Comment: Yes. The enumeration approach is the only usable way I see. Anyways, I accept this as the only usable answer - since the multi-file problem is another story altogether!

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it does not allow to document the individual values. I have an issue with JSDoc. https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/1065

Comment: I don't see how this can be ok. Parameter "a" is expected to be an object with two properties, but you provide a string to the function.

Comment: @LidelnKyoku - It works, because the type is *declared* to be an enum and then gets special treatment. `Enumeration` is not an object *type* but an enum type with string values. [it does work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&resolveJsonModule=true&filetype=js#code/PQKhCgAIUhRA7ArgW0gZwC4CcCW8DmkAbgIYA2iApmgHRQwAClSqA3prgQL73DgDGAe3iY4LSlhIYcwyAF5IrKJBUB5AHKwAXJABEAFQAWlSCwBGEyMMq6ANMpX6A6qp26AgukpD4AE1MoFli64FwA3ODgoBDQkADKJMgADmSUdLEMSSSSbAgoElIy8FyQJFbwJoIAZpAYxpDM+ZLSsqQU1OkgfFWI8Pwt8LXUGAAUJACUipAOpRHAwCoAegD8oRGRGMMjecgFAzQasONAA)

Answer (score 207):

As of [late 2014](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/629#issuecomment-58766768) in jsdoc3 you have the possibility to write:

```
/**
 * @param {('rect'|'circle'|'ellipse')} shapeType - The allowed type of the shape
 */
Shape.prototype.getType = function (shapeType) {
  return this.type;
};
```

Of course this will not be as reusable as a dedicated enum but in many cases a dummy enum is an overkill if it is only used by one function.

See also: https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/629#issue-31314808

Comment: This is a better solution if you know that the param type will never change.

Answer (score 76):

What about:

```
/**
 * @typedef {"keyvalue" | "bar" | "timeseries" | "pie" | "table"} MetricFormat
 */

/**
 * @param format {MetricFormat}
 */
export function fetchMetric(format) {
    return fetch(`/matric}`, format);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, is it possible to list the values from existing array? let say, I have array of string values, and I need to limit the input to the text that includes in this array

Answer (score 12):

I don't think there's a formal way of writing allowed values in [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html).

You certainly can write something like `@param {String('up'|'down'|'left'|'right')}` like user [b12toaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2477619/b12toaster) mentioned.

[image]

But, by taking reference from [APIDocjs](http://apidocjs.com/#param-api-param), here's what I use for writing constrained values, aka *allowedValues*.

```
/**
 * Set the arrow position of the tooltip
 * @param {String='up','down','left','right'} position pointer position
 */
setPosition(position='left'){
  // YOUR OWN CODE
}
```

Oh yeah, I'm using ES6.

Comment: `@param` does not allow this type of syntax. The most standard way would be `@param {"up"|"down"|"left"|"right"} [position=left] - pointer position`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how the Closure Compiler supports it: you can use "@enum" to define a restricted type.   You don't actually have to define the values in enum definition. For instance, I might define an "integer" type like:

```
/** @enum {number} */
var Int = {};

/** @return {Int} */
function toInt(val) {
  return /** @type {Int} */ (val|0);
}
```

Int is generally assignable to "number" (it is a number) but "number" is not assignable to "Int" without some coercion (a cast).

Comment: But that doesn't restrict the possible values of `Int`. That's the part I'm not sure is possible.

Comment: It does as much as any other type annotation or enum in JS.  The restriction comes from how you write the code: every "cast" is a red flag. If you limit the casts to value factories then you get what you want: you can't assign 'number' to 'Int' without a warning.

Comment: It still doesn't restrict the values of {Int}. :-(

Comment: Sure it does, you restrict the value of Int by limiting how it is created and the restriction is done when the value is created.  A raw number can not be assigned which is all you need.