# JSDoc: Define allowed values of parameter which has string type

Tags: javascript, jsdoc3

I'm using JSDoc and I would like to add the info to my documentation which value a parameter should have.

In this example you can see, that the parameter `operator` has string type. But furthermore there can only be `open` or `close` as valid value of the parameter

```
/**
 * Description
 * @param {string='open','close'}  operator
 */
```

What is the correct syntax to add this information?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use a type union `|`:

```
/**
 * Description
 * @param {('open'|'close')}  operator
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

From a design perspective, if your pram is restricted to a list of options you should create an `Enum` of those options for reusability. see this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19322623/5633515

Alternatively, you can create wrapper functions like

```
_changeState(state){...} // assumed private
close(){ _changeState('close')}
open(){_changeState('open')}
```